# master node to control two or three others

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, ros-hydro, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to make a single app that controls a turtlebot robot. I would like to be able to run the gmapping software that makes a map at one point and then switch to the software that navigates the map, all from the interface of my program. I am under the impression that these elements don't work well together, so I want to be able to start one node that does the gmapping and then stop that node and start the node that does the navigating -- all from my program.

I was searching on line and I found that there used to be software called rosspawn. (I'm not even sure if this would do what I want) anyway I don't think it's part of hydro???

So what I'm looking for is a master node that allows me to configure several other nodes at startup and then allows me to start and stop these other nodes either by service or through some topic publishing scheme. Any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/125671/master-node-to-control-two-or-three-others/) by [david.c.liebman](https://answers.ros.org/users/9071/david.c.liebman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2014-02-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The turtlebot has an app manager and [rapps](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps/tree/hydro/turtlebot_core_apps/rapps) (robot apps) that bringup and teardown different tasks without having to completely tear down the robot. All you need do is create a program that interacts with the /start_app and /stop_app handles of the app manager.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2014-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [david.c.liebman](https://answers.ros.org/users/9071/david.c.liebman/) on 2014-02-05**:
/start_app and /stop_app are found where? and where does the app manager get started in the 'rocon_launch turtlebot_bringup bringup.concert' invocation? I see a '/turtlebot/app_list' but nothing that looks like '/stop_app'

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2014-02-06**:
You don't need the concert launcher - this starts two master and you need to make sure you have the right master set in your console. Instead use turtlebot_bringup/minimal_with_appmanager.launch. For more information see: http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/hydro/App%20Manager

**Comment by [david.c.liebman](https://answers.ros.org/users/9071/david.c.liebman/) on 2014-02-10**:
now I have questions about how to make this all work. See my new question: http://answers.ros.org/question/127411/using-services-from-android_map_manager-and-other-rapps/